# Extra spaces when printing

Tags: python, whitespace, string-formatting

I've read through a number of the python whitespace removal questions and answers but haven't been able to find what I'm looking for.  Here is a small program that shows a specific example of the issue.  I greatly appreciate your help.

```
import random

math_score = random.randint(200,800)
math_guess = int(input("\n\nWhat score do you think you earned on the math section (200 to 800)?\t"))
print ("\n\n\nOn the math section, you guessed",math_guess,", and your actual score was",math_score,"!")
```

So here's my issue:

When I execute the program, I get the following results:

`On the math section, you guessed 600 , and your actual score was 717 !`

I would like to remove the space that follows each variable in the sentence.  In this case the space between 600 and the "," and the space between 717 and the "!".

Is there a standard way to approach this issue?

Comment: The space is automatically inserted for you when you separate the arguments with commas. Take a look at string formatting (as mentioned below), which would allow you to pass the arguments in in a more dynamic way.

Comment: On the topic of coding style, it's strongly recommended you do not insert a space in between a function and its arguments.  So, `print("string")` isntead of `print ("string")`

Comment: in python 3 I believe they have the `sep` keyword to the `print` statement that allows you to define the `,` separator ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, [format](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatstrings) your string:

```
print("... you guessed {}, and ... was {}!".format(math_guess, math_score))
```

Comment: I removed the space between the function and the argument to conform to the coding style, and also formatted the argument with the {} and .format notation and it worked like a charm.  Thank you!

Comment: Andrew: I'm new to this, so could you explain why it's not proper coding style to include a space between a function and an argument, but it is proper to include a space between a variable and its value.  This seems inconsistent to me but I'm sure there's a good reason.

Comment: Why "color" vs "colour"?  Like most things in programming and human languages, it's convention.  What is convention, but the tastes of one group that won the popularity war.  You can go all CCCummings and drop capitalization and punctuation and not be "wrong", but you'll sure annoy the %^&* out of everyone and can expect they'll annoy you right back.

Comment: @user1741368: You're welcome! :) You should then probably mark this answer as [accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/177799), in order to close your question; you can do that by checking the mark on the side.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [format](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) the entire line into a single string, then print that string.

```
print ("\n\n\nOn the math section, you guessed {0}, and your actual score was {1}!".format(math_guess, math_score))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print ("\n\n\nOn the math section, you guessed",math_guess,", and your actual score was",math_score,"!", sep ='')
```

if this is py3+ i think

```
print ("\n\n\nOn the math section, you guessed"+str(math_guess)+", and your actual score was"+str(math_score)+"!")
```

should work if not

or use string formatting as others have suggested...

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
print "\n\n\nOn the math section, you guessed %d and your actual score was %d!" % (math_guess, math_score)
```

You can read more at [Built-in Types](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting)

Comment: you should use the `"{}".format` syntax since this kind is depreciated (but will stick around for a long time (TBH I still use this format all the time)

Comment: I did not know that this is deprecated, thanks, will read about it.